# Php and js redirection error

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, youtube

I'm trying to do a randomizer for a youtube playlist and I encountered this problem, when I "redirect" to the page I was supposed to be redirected, it actually redirects me to "www.youtube.com" instead of "www.youtube.com/watch?v={videoID}" just like I would have set redirection to  "www.youtube.com/watch?v=" without the video ID.

Can someone help me out to get the redirection I wanted ?

PS: Code is below

```
<?php 
    srand(12);
    $x=mt_rand(1,27);
        $y=$x-1;
        $index=strval($y);
    if($index==""){$index="0";}else{$index=strval($y);}
        $list="PLY3Z88WiyNeqKK2NDtx4ajmvntxmXKVG5";
        $v="0";
        switch($x){
            case 1:
                $v="tLkEFH3KFVI";
            break;

            case 2:
                $v="ie84bcGoSUI";
            break;
                case 3:
                $v="kLKTlyjS8pU";
            break;
            case 4:
                $v="-fwtEE0w6DM";
                break;
            case 5:
                $v="7MPIRR0Fs_g";
                break;
            case 6:
                $v="vojFyoClC1s";
                break;
            case 7:
                $v="0fUv2xNAwIE";
                break;
            case 8:
                $v="fkCxqd3OWD8";
                break;
            case 9:
                $v="5RCedaSoMHk";
                break;
            case 10:
                $v="ME1RKZXxWbU";
                break;
            case 11:
                $v="p7MFuczjjAE";
                break;
            case 12:
                $v="nz5ZI6iDDCc";
                break;
            case 13:
                $v="-HlvqQtmoRY";
                break;
            case 14:
                $v="TIGuXAV9OyA";
                break;
            case 15:
                $v="RQG3pG1prVg";
                break;
            case 16:
                $v="A6GUSRu5_Zs";
                break;
            case 17:
                $v="uL_B_Sd0Jyo";
                break;

            case 18:
                $v="eVNASb7mg8c";
                break;
            case 19:
                $v="9KbxBDKDL-U";
                break;
            case 20:
                $v="_uRmVNJuTVI";
                break;
            case 21:
                $v="Ba_iPeWWJLg";
                break;
            case 22:
                $v="P8zFLKnOBZ";
                break;
            case 23:
                $v="5QwmpQ1pw9E";
                break;
            case 24:
                $v="U54nqXz9icA&";
                break;
            case 25:
                $v="o5mV1rbZjs";
                break;
            case 26:
                $v="mntpfq2ajFQ";
                break;
            case 27:
                $v="aqvtL-LoSXA";
                break;
            default:
                $v="_uRmVNJuTVI";
        }

?>

    <center><img src="redir.png" alt="redirecting"/></center>



<script>
    var kk='<?php print( json_encode($v)); ?>';
    var zz="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+kk
 setTimeout(function(){document.location.href=zz},2000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a syntax error in javascript.

Missing semicolon:

```
 var zz="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+kk; //here
 console.log(zz); //what does this show? 
 setTimeout(function(){document.location.href=zz},2000)
```

Comment: Ok I haven't finished yet :) I have updated my answer.

Comment: A missing semicolon at the end of a line is actually not an error in JavaScript. I'd recommend always using them though.

Comment: That's true. I forgot to transform myself from other code conventions i am used to follow

Comment: Maybe I'm doin'it wrong but it doesn't show anything

Comment: Well, that's the point, so we see javascript would redirect correctly, if the kk is filled properly. Could you investigate or post, what is actually in the source code of the browser (CTRL+U) in these lines of js code? If 'var zz="...?v=" is filled?

Comment: Yeah. So as you could see as well, your PHP code hasn't compiled between quotation marks.

Comment: What should I do then ?

Comment: So by looking again to the question, that's not a php even javascript error. It's issue with php compiler or something. How wonderful is the world of programming.

Comment: RIP random start in playlist project